# Adjust Margins in Qt Fusion theme

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt5

My layout looks correct when I view it in the `windowsxp` and `windowsvista` (shown) styles, but when I use Qt's `Fusion` theme extra padding is added between group box elements.

I can't figure out where to change the margins so that the gaps (in red) disappear.

Changing the margins of the layout, setting them to 0 from the designer, doesn't appear to make an appreciable change to size of the gaps when I apply the Fusion theme.

[image: Qt Vista Theme]

[image: Qt Fusion theme with annoying gaps]

Comment: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-44056